# Gdal format command not found

Tags: qgis, gdal, mac

I am trying to clip a raster image based on a vector mask layer and I am encountering this error: `Gdal format command not found.`

I am on a Macintosh and my QGIS version is 3.4.

Comment: Could you edit your question by explaining how you tried to clip your raster ?